# Magento Generates System.log as Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, magento, currency, magento-1.8

In My Magento Project => System.log generates following Error

```
2014-06-28T12:34:58+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in
 D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\DOMAINNAME\app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\directory\currency-top.phtml on line 9
```

The Code at Line 9 is as follows :

```
$last_item = end(($this->getCurrencies()));
```

I referred this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698963/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference), But No Success

Comment: try this. `$var = $this->getCurrencies();$last_item = end($var);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that end requires a reference, because it modifies the internal representation of the array (i.e. it makes the current element pointer point to the last element).

Set into a variable the result of the "$this->getCurrencies()" function, and pass this variable to the end() function

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please try this one

```
$getCurrencies = $this->getCurrencies();

$last_item = end(($getCurrencies));
```